# Tasks in javascript?

Tags: javascript

#### Essence of the question

The real reason why I ask this question - not because I want solve my problem. I want to know how to work with tasks in JavaScript. I don't need thread paralleling and other stuff. There are two parts of computing smth: IO and CPU. I want to make CPU computing works in time between ajax request sended and ajax request get answer from server. There is obstacle: from one function I run many tasks and this function must produce Task, that waits all runned tasks, process results of them and returns some value. That's all I want. Of course, if you post another way to solve my problem, I will vote for your answer and can set it as solution if there are no other answers about tasks.

Why  I describe my problem, not just asking about tasks? Ask guys who minused and closed this question a time ago.

#### Problem

My problem: I want to traverse a tree in JavaScript to find the smallest possible parsing. I have a dictionary of words stored in the form of a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). When a user gives an input string, I need to get a count of words that match the input string and is the shortest combination of words.

#### Example:

1. My dictionary contains these words: `my, code, js, myj, scode`
2. A user types `myjscode`
3. I traverse my tree of words and find that the input matches `myj + scode` and `my + js + code`
4. Since the first parsing is the shortest, my function returns 2 (the number of words in the shortest parsing)

#### My Problem

My dictionary tree is huge, so I can't load it fully. To fix this, I want to do some lazy-loading. Each node of the tree is either loaded and points to child nodes or is not loaded yet and contains a link to the data to be loaded.

So, I need to make node look up calls while I'm traversing the tree. Since these calls are asynchronous, I want to be able to explore other traversals while loading tree nodes. This will improve the response time for the user.

How I want to solve this problem:

My lookup function will return a task. I can call that task and get its results. Once I traverse to the loaded node, I can then make multiple calls to load child nodes and each call returns a task. Since these "tasks" are individual bits of functionality, I can queue them up and execute them while I'm waiting for ajax calls to return.

So, I want to know which library I can use, or how I can emulate tasks in javascript (I'm thinking of tasks as they exist in C#).

There is restriction: no server-side code, only ajax to precompiled dictionaries in javascript. Why? It has to be used as password complexity checker.

Comment: https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: Aaaaa. Guys. What is unclear in my question? I want to get ability of creating tasks and waiting them, and processing their results. I have provided to you example, how can I do that in c#; and I want to do that same in Javascript. I asked you for a library, because I haven't googled it. What's unclear?

Comment: @RoelvanUden well, async.js is nice library but it describes asynchron work it terms of `processFunc(what, whatAfter?)`. But I need to to populate tasks and wait their end. Can you vote for reopen?

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot can you nominate question for reopen?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33147/discussion-between-rustytheboyrobot-and-nsinreal)

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot I said that I haven't googled, not that I haven't tried to google

Comment: The closest analogue to this in JS is a "promise"—essentially, an object that does some sort of task then, if it successfully completes (is "fulfilled"), calls some other code. Does this sound like what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say in your question:

> Of course, if you post another way to solve my problem, I will vote for your answer and can set it as solution if there are no other answers about tasks.

Good; sorry, but I don't think that c# style tasks is the right solution here.

I'll accept (although I don't think it's correct) your assertion that for security reasons you have to do everything client-side.  As an aside, might I point out that if you are scared of somebody snooping (because you have a security weakness) then passing lots of requests for part of the password is just as insecure as passing one request?  Sorry, I appear to have done so without consent!

Nonetheless, I will attempt to answer with a broad outline how I would approach your problem if, indeed, you had to do it in JavaScript; I would use promises.  Probably jQuery's Deferred implementation, to be specific.  I'll give  a very rough pseudo-code outline here.

### Overview

You start with a nicely structured Trie.  Using recursion I would build up a nicely structured "solution tree", which would be a nested array of arrays; this would give the flexibility of being able to respond to the user with a specific message... however, since you seem prepared to lose that bonus and only want a single digit as a solution, I will outline a slightly simpler approach that you could, if needed, adapt to return arrays of the form (from your example):

```
[["myj"],["scode"],["my"],["js"],["code"]]
```

I mention this structure here also, partly, as it helps explain the approach I am adopting.

### Notes

I will refer to "nodes" and "valueNodes" in your Trie.  I consider "nodes" to be *anything* and "valueNodes" to be nodes with values.

The recursive promiseToResolveRemainder will resolve 0 for "couldn't do it"; it will only reject the promise if something went wrong (say, the webservice wasn't available).

### Dodgy, hacky, untested Pseudo-code

```
var minDepth=0; //Zero value represents failure to match (Impossible?  Not if you are accepting unicode passwords!)

function promiseToResolveRemainder(remainder,fragmentSoFar){
    deferred = new jQuery.Deferred();
    nextChar = remainder.substring(0,1);
    if (remainder.length==1){
      //Insert code here to:
      //Test for fragmentSoFar+nextChar being a valueNode.
      //If so, resolve(1)... otherwise resolve(0)
      //!!Note that, subtly, this catches the case where fragmentSoFar is an empty string :)
      return;
    }
    remainder = remainder.substring(1);
    promiseToFindValueNode(fragmentSoFar+nextChar).then(
       function(success){
           //We know that we *could* terminate the growing fragment here and proceed
           //But we could also proceed from here by adding to the fragment
           var firstPathResolvedIn = 0;
           var secondPathResolvedIn = 0;
           promiseToResolveRemainder(remainder,'').then(
               function(resolvedIn){
                   firstPathResolvedIn = resolvedIn + 1;
               }
           ).then(
               promiseToResolveRemainder(remainder,fragmentSoFar+nextChar).then(
                   function(resolvedIn){
                       secondPathResolvedIn = resolvedIn;
                       if(!firstPathResolvedIn==0 and !secondPathResolvedIn==0){
                           deffered.resolve(Math.min(firstPathResolvedIn,secondPathResolvedIn));
                       }
                       deferred.resolve(Math.max(firstPathResolvedIn,secondPathResolvedIn));//Sloppy, but promises cannot be resolved twice, so no sweat (I know, that's a *dirty* trick!)
                   }
               )
           )
       },
       function(failure){
           //We know that we *need* at least a node or this call to
           //promiseToResolveRemainder at this iteration has been a failure.
           promiseToFindNode(fragmentSoFar+nextChar).then(
               function(resolvedIn){
                   //ok, so we *could* proceed from here by adding to the fragment
                   promiseToResolveRemainder(remainder,fragmentSoFar+nextChar).then(
                       function(resolvedIn){
                           deferred.resolve(resolvedIn);
                       }
                   )
               },
               function(failedBecause){
                   //ooops!  We've hit a dead end, we can't complete from here.
                   deferred.resolve(0);
               }
           )
       },
    )
    return deferred.Promise();
}
```

I am not particularly proud of this untested kludgy attempt at code (and I'm not about to write your solution for you!), but I am proud of the approach and am sure that it will yield a robust, reliable and efficient solution to your problem.  Unfortunately, you seem to be dependent on a *lot* of webService calls... I would be *very* tempted, therefore, to abstract away any calls to the webService and check them through a local cache first.

Comment: Nice work, Andy. Promises (in this case, jQuery's `Deferred`) are exactly what @nsinreal is looking for.

Comment: Why thank you Jordan; I see you got there six minutes before me!  But maybe not as extensively... I hope I've read the original question correctly and read between the lines where necessary... it sounds like the OP was going to build the tree and parse the tree as separate concerns... hopefully I've been able to show that one could kill two birds with one stone using recursion! :)

Comment: @AndyH: well, what I must say. I haven't read your code, so don't care about it. I have read just now documentation about [`deferred object`] (http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and it seems to provide nice syntax for long async operations. Thanks. That's all. I'll mark your answer as right

Comment: @AndyH: the real reason, why I don't want to use server-side - I want to write library. So, cuz that is a password checker, I can't use my server, cuz that supposed to be used by many guys, on server-side there can be PHP, Node.js, ASP.NET or anything  and I can't write this tool for all languages. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @nsinreal I'm glad that the concept was useful to you; I still don't quite understand your non-server-side argument, but I guess it's academic.  I'm going to assume that you have salts and hashes for your actual passwords and that any communication between the client and the server (especially when negotiating new passwords) is over a secure connection... if so then I don't see the problem doing the work on the server; and if not, I don't see how you can have any real security at all, and running the code on the client won't gain you a whole lot of anything!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you are looking for, but you might try WebWorkers.

A simple example is at: https://github.com/afshinm/50k but you can google for more.

Note - web workers will be highly browser dependent and *do not* run in a separate task on the machine.